# How can I set different datasets for different pickerviews on the same view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I've seen a ton of tutorials that show how to do this with a multi-column picker view, but for the app I'm working on I have 2 picker views with two entirely different arrays to populate the data from 2 different arrays?

Comment: It's perfectly possible. What have you done? What is not working?

Comment: I currently have two arrays set (for short array and arrayMD) each with a separate @property UIPickerview in the .h file, and individual titleForRow and numberOfcompoents. But when I run the app I end up with both pickerviews displaying the same data. My guess is I need a way to specify the picker views datasource, but not entirely sure how to specify that

Comment: The answer tells you. The delegate and datasource methods all take a reference to the picker view. you just need to filter your method based on that. Or provided different delegate and datasource instances for each picker view.

Comment: Please use the `xcode` tag only for questions related to the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` or somewhere like that:

```
UIPickerView *firstPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
firstPickerView.dataSource = self;
firstPickerView.delegate = self;

UIPickerView *secondPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
secondPickerView.dataSource = self;
secondPickerView.delegate = self;

NSArray *firstPickerSource = ...  // populate with some data
NSArray *secondPickerSource = ... // populate with some data
```

Later, in your dataSource and delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView == firstPickerView)
        return [firstPickerSource count];
    else
        return [secondPickerSource count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView == firstPickerView)
        return [firstPickerSource objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [secondPickerSource objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Alternatively you could `tag` your pickerViews when you create them and see if `pickerView.tag == 1` or something like that instead of `pickerView == firstPickerView`

Comment: This turned out to be the easiest way to accomplish what I needed. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

All the `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods have `UIPickerView *` parameter.

Comment: Or even create separate delegate/datasources for each picker